# How do elemental shields work?

Tags: genshin-impact

In Genshin Impact you can pick up crystals that will generate an elemental shield around your character like this:

[image]

I find these pretty handy when fighting certain enemies but the in-game guide doesn't really explain how they work in detail - specifically:

- How strong are these shields/does a character's stats affect their strength? How do they compare to the shields that Noelle/Diona/etc. can generate with their elemental skills?
- What happens if you take elemental damage of a different type to that of the shield?
- What happens if you pick up another crystal of the same type - does the shield strength stack, or does it simply reset the duration of the shield?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Be careful that asking too many questions could make the post to be flagged and closed as too broad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**How strong are the cristallize shields and how does the type affect the damage?**

Shields gained from picking up the Elemental Shards dropped by Crystallize reactions have shield health based on the level and Elemental Mastery of the character that triggered the reaction. These shields additionally have 250% effectiveness against elemental damage of the same element; in other words, they only take 40% as much damage when absorbing damage of their own element.

```
HP(Crystallize Shield) = HP(Base Crystallize Shield) * (1+%ElementalMastery-Bonus)
```

Base Crystallize Shield HP is only affected by the character level.

| Character Level | Base Shield HP |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 91 |
| 10 | 159 |
| 20 | 304 |
| 30 | 438 |
| 40 | 585 |
| 50 | 787 |
| 60 | 1030 |
| 70 | 1315 |
| 80 | 1597 |
| 90 | 1851 |

(Data for Version/1.6 - current Version/2.4)

Further increased by Elemental Mastery(EM) with the given formula:

```
444 * EM / (EM + 1400)
```

For further details, see [Crystallize in Genshin Impact Wiki](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Crystallize).

When the shield takes damage, the damage is scaled down based on the shield's elemental damage absorption bonuses and the active character's Shield Strength attribute.

```
DMG(Crystallize Shield) = DMG(Incoming) / (%ElementBonus * (1+%Shield Strength(Active Character)))
where %ElementBonus = 2.5(=250%) if Element(DMG) = Element(Shield), else 1(=100%)
```

If the damage exceeds the shield's health, the damage taken by character is the excess damage multiplied by the same shield bonus multipliers.

**What happens if I pick up another shard?**

Picking up a new shard simply replaces the old Cristallize-Shield with the new one. Only one cristallized shield may be active at a time. Multiple character shields may exist at the same time, just replacing itself (with [Thoma](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Thoma) as exception who may buff his own shield further). However, as stated by @SPArcheon in the comments, they take damage simultaneously.

**Can I compare shields of different characters?**

The shields of other characters such as Diona, Noelle and Zhongli simply got their own base HP and absorption. For a comparison of these, you can look up [Shields/Comparison](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Shields/Comparison).

Credits go to [Genshin Impact Fandom Wiki](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Shields#Crystallize_Shields), where it's well explained in even further detail. All data for current Version 2.4.

Comment: "Character shields also override each other and itself" - not true, [most shields can stack.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50ggS.jpg). The real problem is that they also take damage at the same time, so there is no benefit to [stack them](https://genshin.mihoyo.com/en/news/detail/6085) other than reduced down times.

Comment: As for the crystallize thing, I *think* that Geo crystalize shield is peculiar in the fact it is the only one that does not override other element crystallization.

Comment: @SPArcheon Ty for the hint, I corrected my answer regarding the character shields. As for the geo shields, these aren't normal crystalized shields and only occour when fighting Geovishap Hatchlings as far as I know. They may stack with other crystalized shields and have a 150% effectiveness against elements, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: the Pure Geo Hypostasis was another example, but it is kinda extinct right now...

Comment: Relevant: [KQM theorycrafting library evidence](https://library.keqingmains.com/evidence/combat-mechanics/elemental-effects/transformative-reactions#crystallize) regarding crystallize shields replacing existing crystallize shields.